# Flex / AIR, how to set focus on a UI Control, Button, etc?

Tags: apache-flex, air, focus

So, I'm trying to set focus on a specific button when the app launches (or later based on certain events), so that the user can simply hit return to press the button. None of the following approaches work however.

`protected function group1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void

{

    //btnBrowse.setFocus();

    focusManager.setFocus(btnBrowse);

}`

Comment: Did you make the Button focusable?

Comment: You mean Button.focusEnabled = true? That should be on by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
protected function group1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  callLater(btnBrowse.setFocus);
}
```

Comment: And it doesn't always work. It works in this particular case, but not for example on other events when I want to set focus on other buttons. I will try and make an example with Timer if I'll have some more time to devote to this.

Answer (score 0):

To hit the return button and have it automatically execute the `Click` event, in the panel, canvas, etc where the user is in, set `defaultButton="{buttonid}"`.

Comment: Doesn't work and it does not display any highlight or something around button.

Answer (score 0):

Flex doesn't have focus on application startup, js does.
You need to find some tricks on google to pass the focus from the browser to flash.

Here is the first one I found : http://edsyrett.wordpress.com/2008/08/15/focus-issues-in-flex/

Comment: It's not browser, it's AIR as I said in the title of the post. So unfortunately that won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer is still relevant, but try adding both.

Make the button as default for the application, and add focus to it on the creation complete event.