# Auto select TextInput (FormItem)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a login form consisting of a Form with two TextInput's. I want the Form, or the *username* TextInput field to be automatically selected when the user enters, so he does not have to left click the TextInput field before entering his *username*. Do anyone know how i can achieve this?

> ```
> <mx:Form x="223" y="186" defaultButton="{submitButton}">
>     <mx:FormItem label="Username">
>         <mx:TextInput id="userName"/>
>     </mx:FormItem>
>     <mx:FormItem label="Password">
>         <mx:TextInput id="password" displayAsPassword="true"/>  
>     </mx:FormItem>
>     <mx:FormItem>
>         <mx:Button id="submitButton" label="Login" click="submitLogin()"/>
>     </mx:FormItem>
> </mx:Form>
> ```

Comment: You need to set focus for it. Check this out:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/23/setting-focus-in-flex-using-the-focus-manager/

Comment: This may help: -- userName.setFocus()

Comment: As I've commented on @Thinhbk 's answer, setting focus isn't going to be sufficient for a login box. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643079/setfocus-in-flex/8657202#8657202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
focusManager.setFocus(userName);
```

Comment: If it's a login box, that's going to be insufficient, since the Flash Player doesn't have focus in the HTML page yet.

Comment: In that case, try to use this approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936058/flex-air-how-to-set-focus-on-a-ui-control-button-etc

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your help. The userName TextInput gets focus and is highlighted, but I still cant write directly into it without clicking it. Anyone know why?

Comment: Ahhh, i guess the reason why it doesnt work is what @RIAstar said? Ill check out the tutorial now :)

Comment: @RIAstar : I get this error "TypeError: el is null" When i attempt to use the Farata solution. I tried replacing the "%objectID%" with "prima" the id I defined in my index.html file but with no luck
<noscript>
   <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
   id="prima" width="100%" height="100%"

Comment: @Sebastian: try this approach: http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2010/08/31/set-flex-to-focus-on-application-load/  or in SOF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745786/how-to-place-cursor-in-textinput-in-flex3

Comment: @Sebastian Are you embedding it with swfObject? Try embedding that JS function directly into the page (with the "%objectID%" token replaced of course) and see what happens if you call it from the console. Also, are you on Safari? They say the solution doesn't work on Safari yet.

Comment: @Thinhbk If the OP's on Safari the issue will probably remain: `NOTE: This will not work in Safari, Chrome, or any other browser that leverages Webkit`. Some fixes are suggested in the comments though

Comment: @RIAstar: I absolutely agree, the approach is just a work around for the situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help to both of you! I dont know why i didn't get the Farata solution to work, but I got this solution to work: http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2010/08/31/set-flex-to-focus-on-application-load/